# Why do some angular $scope functions "return" an operation?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've come across some code that looks like this:

```
$scope.open = function($event) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();
    return $scope.opened = true;
 };
```

Why is this returning an assignment? What does this do? Is there a benefit to doing or not doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is basically:

```
$scope.open = function($event) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();
    $scope.opened = true;
    return $scope.opened;
 };
```

So the benefit is that it saves one line of code. Probably not worth it.

It might also be compiled CoffeeScript code, which originally looked like:

```
$scope.open = ($event) ->
    $event.preventDefault()
    $event.stopPropagation()
    $scope.opened = true
```

CoffeeScript always returns the result of the last line in a method, so it may return values from functions which you'd expect to not normally return anything.

Comment: This makes sense. So why return anything at all in this case? Why not simply remove the last line of your first code snippet? Is there a downside to this? I assume that no functions calling $scope.open will expect or use a return value.

Comment: Yes, probably better without it in this case. There might be times when there is more than one class which implements an open method, and perhaps one of them might have a disabled state, which returns false from open if it is disabled, rather then actually opening. But that doesn't seem to be the case here, and such a method would probably be better called tryOpen instead of open anyway.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Thanks! I wasn't sure if I was missing out on a best practice of "always returning" from a function. Seems not. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Actually there is a design technique related to that, called writing [pure functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function). Since pure functions don't have side effects, really they must always return values, otherwise there wouldn't be any point in calling them. When writing code using [functional programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) it is best practice to make as many (or even all) functions pure, then they would always return values.

Answer (score 0):

This will make the function return true, while at the same time setting `$scope.opened` to true.  It is equivalent to doing

```
$scope.opened = true;
return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Douglas's answer that it's not worth it. In fact I would go as far as saying that it's obfuscated coding. It's one thing to return something like `return x===y` in which case you are actually comparing x and y and returning true if they are equal and false otherwise. But returning the result of an assignment doesn't make much sense.